# Save Arel Query Syntax (not its result) In a Database Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have an app which has many rules that can change.  I do not want to have to stop the app, and change the code (scopes) every time I need to change one of the rules.  The rules do not follow a pattern.  I'd like to create an admin-view where I can simply alter an Arel-syntax-based rule.  To do this, the Arel-syntax would need to be stored in a table.

I have a Rules table with a name, description, and some other cols.  I am considering adding a "query" column, to store the Arel Query that generates the result for this rule.  Then I can get rid of the 'case' code block and scope-list, which gets longer by the day.

I cannot find where anyone else is doing this, so I wonder if I am off-base?  If not, how would I pull the value and apply it in a controller?

Example: A controller-method receives params which tells it what rule to apply.  It pulls the Rule instance and its query value - but how to take that query-result (a string) and "run" it in that controller?

Comment: Check https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku which might help.

Comment: Thanks, but dentaku seems to be a calculator.  I need to save and run arel-queries against the DB.